# async calculation of Fibonacci slower than sequence calculation

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous

I'm trying this code for calculation of Fibonacci series:

```
unsigned long fib_async(unsigned long n) {
    if (n<2) {
        return n;
    }
    else {
        auto res1 = async(fib_async, n-1);
        auto res2 = async(fib_async, n-2);

        return res1.get() + res2.get();
    }
}
```

Why is this code slower than classical:

```
unsigned long fib(unsigned long n) {
    return n<2 ? n : fib(n-2) + fib(n-1);
}
```

?

Synchronous version for n=40 lasts 0.7 seconds on my 8-core i7 CPU. Asynchronous example for n=40 lasts more than 1 minute and it seems to run on one CPU core only.

What am I doing wrong? I'm testing it on a Linux machine with gcc 4.8.4.

Comment: Your calculations are trivial enough that mutli-threading just adds overhead.

Comment: @SLaks But why it doesn't use other CPU cores at all?

Comment: You might need to use `std::launch_async` as first parameter, but that will probably make things worse if a thread is launched for each call to async.

Comment: @juanchopanza Nice fork bomb. :) So it worked, I just need to limit count of running threads.

Answer (score 2):

You're effectively replacing the overhead of a function call (in your recursive version) with the overhead of launching a thread that calls the function (and waiting after each thread completes).    It's hard to envisage any scenario where your multithread code will run to completion faster than the recursive one.

Of course, if you really care about performance (and not trying for particularly large n) you'd use a closed form for computing the Fibonacci sequence.   There is a relationship to the square root of 5 .....

Answer (score 0):

For a Fibonacci sequence, each *successive* calculation relies on a *prior* result, so it cannot be parallelized.  All you are doing is introducing synchronization overhead resulting in wait states.

Comment: But you need *two* Fibonacci numbers to get a new one. These two numbers can be calculated independently.

Comment: *But they cannot be calculated until prior results are available.*  That pretty much defeats the purpose of having multiple threads: creating a bunch of threads that each have to wait until the work of a previous thread is done (at which point that previous thread will be terminating) is certainly not going to speed anything up.

Comment: @frasnian: No, because he's doing fibonacci the naive way.  He can calculate `f(n-1)` and `f(n-2)` in parallel.  (it still won't help much)

Comment: Even so - where is the value for *n* going to come from?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: exactly.  And the caller gets it from... and so on and so on.  Essentially you are trying to create a parallel solution to a linear problem.  The fact that OP want to use a recursive method for Fib instead of an iterative approach doesn't mean anything - the very definition of the sequence means that to calculate each N in the sequence, you *must have* the prior 2 values. You can create all the threads you want - they'll just be waiting for earlier threads to finish before they can even proceed.

Comment: The recursive solution is the very opposite of linear.  Each call in turn spawns two new calls. If the computation was something substantial (rather than just +), this wouldn't be a terrible use of threads (in the sense that it would saturate your available cores).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I did not say that recursion itself is linear - I am saying that calculating a Fibonacci number by simple addition is inherently linear.  Or do you disagree with that assertion?

Comment: What is your definition of "linear"?  Yes, each calculation depends on another layer of results to be calculated, but that's not the reason that multi-threading offers no benefit here.

Comment: Would "sequential" be preferable?

Comment: Sure. But it still doesn't matter! Do you agree that the OP's algorithm quickly spawns 2^N threads that would all run in parallel if there were sufficient cores available?  The only thing missing is actual computation; each thread does nothing.  So our performance is limited by overhead, not by the notion of sequence.